# Render item from items list in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm newbie in Backbone. I started with [Todo MVC](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/backbone) and now I'm trying to write test app. In my app, I've project's list and I want after click to one project to show this project in view. My code below:

**projects.json** :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "First project",
    "issues": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "title": "main issue",
        "comment": "lorem ipsum",
        "time": 30
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "title": "second issue",
        "comment": "lorem ipsum",
        "time": 60
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Second project",
    "issues": [
      {
        "id": 21,
        "title": "main issue",
        "comment": "lorem ipsum",
        "time": 90
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "title": "on more issue",
        "comment": "lorem ipsum",
        "time": 60
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Test project",
    "issues": [
      {
        "id": 31,
        "title": "main issue",
        "comment": "lorem ipsum",
        "time": 20
      },
      {
        "id": 32,
        "title": "second issue",
        "comment": "lorem ipsum",
        "time": 50
      },
      {
        "id": 33,
        "title": "new issue",
        "comment": "lorem ipsum",
        "time": 40
      },
      {
        "id": 34,
        "title": "recently added issue",
        "comment": "lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum",
        "time": 60
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**project.js** :

```
var Project = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        title: '',
        id: null,
        issues: []
    }
});
```

**projects.js** :

```
var ProjectList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Project,
    url: 'data/projects.json'
});
```

**projects-view.js** :

```
var ProjectsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ".project-list",
    template: _.template($('#projects-template').html()),

    render: function(eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(project){
            var projectsTemplate = this.template(project.toJSON());
            $(this.el).append(projectsTemplate);
        }, this);

        return this;
    }
});

var ProjectView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.issue-list',
    template: _.template($('#project-template').html()),

    render: function(eventName) {
        _.each(this.model.models, function(project){
            var projectTemplate = this.template(project.toJSON());
            $(this.el).append(projectTemplate);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});
```

**router.js** :

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '': 'projectsList',
        'project/:id': 'issuesList'
    },

    projectsList: function(){
        var projects = new ProjectList();
        var projectsView = new ProjectsView({model: projects});
        projects.fetch({
            success: function() {
                projectsView.render();
            }
        });
    },
    issuesList: function(id){
        var project = new Project({id: id});
        var projectView = new ProjectView({model: project});
        project.fetch({
            success: function() {
                projectView.render();
            }
        })
    }
});

var router = new Workspace();
Backbone.history.start();
```

**index.html** :

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <ul class="project-list issue-list list-group list-unstyled"></ul>
    </div>
</section>

<script id="projects-template" type="text/template">
<li class="text-center">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item project"><%= title %></a>
</li>
</script>

<script id="project-template" type="text/template">
<li class="text-center">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><%= issues %></a>
</li>
</script>

<script src="lib/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/backbone.localStorage.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/models/project.js"></script>
<script src="js/collection/projects.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/projects-view.js"></script>
<script src="js/routers/router.js"></script>
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: @hindmost, now when I click to some project nothing happens, I asked what do I need, after click to project to view one project with its attributes instead project's list

Comment: First of all don't name a collection as model. In project view, what do you expect `this.model.models` to be..? This looks like you copy pasted some code, changed the names and expected it to work (ask yourself, how can an item view work with the same rendering code of a collection view? They both work with different data structure)... It doesn't work like that... Did you  do basic debugging like checking whether issuesList gets triggered or not?

Answer (score 0):

can't you change the href in the anchor of your projects-template to #projects/<%= id %> instead of # I haven't used backbone before but I believe their router should work that way

Comment: I get projects numbers in address bar

Comment: This is rather a comment. `haven't used` and `believe` without any try to confirm and prove your guess by [looking into the source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) is not so good.

Comment: it's just I don't have enough rep to add a comment but wanted to give a suggestion

Comment: Igor Ivancha so after looking at a few backbone examples I think you need to clean up your old views can you try to follow this and see if it helps you? http://mikeygee.com/blog/backbone.html

Comment: @IgorIvancha can you create a [mcve] demonstrating this..? Because  there is nothing that will redirect to another route in the code you shared